# Unpairing an already-paired Apple wireless keyboard

Tags: bluetooth, wireless-keyboard

I have a Bluetooth Apple Wireless Keyboard that is paired to a machine I cannot currently access to unpair the keyboard. I would like to unpair it from this computer to use it with another machine.

I removed and re-installed the batteries. Then I held the power button on and was expecting to see the green light blinking, but the light went off and the keyboard still does not accept any new pairing.

What do I do next?

Answer (score 20):

Try resetting your keyboard as explained [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2693201?start=0&tstart=0) and [here](http://itecsoftware.com/reset-apple-wireless-keyboard):

1. Turn off the keyboard; better yet, remove the batteries.
2. Click the Bluetooth icon in the upper toolbar, then select “Set Up Bluetooth Device”. If you don't see this icon on your toolbar, click on your System Preferences in the dock, and then Bluetooth in that menu.
3. Wait for the Bluetooth Set Up Assistance to come up and start searching for devices.
4. Insert the batteries and **HOLD** the power button. Do **NOT** let go until step 7.
5. Your keyboard should now appear in the assistant.
6. Select the keyboard from the list and click Continue, **while still holding the power button**.
7. Once you get the pairing code, **let go of the power button** and type in the code.

For more information on pairing,
see [Set up your Apple wireless devices](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1809) at Apple Support.

Comment: Note: This works fine, but you can't let go of the power button until you get to step 7.

Comment: @doub1ejack Thanks, I rephrased step 4 to make it clear.

Comment: "better yet remove the batteries." <= this is the best. Thanks!

Comment: Can someone update this answer for El Capitan? `Set Up Bluetooth Device` isn't there for me.

Comment: This did not work for me for macOS Monterey 12.5.1.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer does not work with the latest OSX (El Capitan). Here are the updated instructions.

Firstly lets all acknowledge, this is not Apple's finest moment in user experience engineering. Onwards.

The Apple bluetooth keyboard is infuriating because the little green light doesn't give you enough information to indicate if it is turning off because battery is dead or for other reasons. So you're a bit blind if the batteries are dead, but otherwise the following instructions should work.

1. Go to System Preferences, then Keyboard
2. Set Up Bluetooth Keyboard...
3. Hold down the power button of the keyboard (the one on the tube, on the right side, not the power button key on the top right of the
   keyboard).
4. If you hold it down for 4 or 5 seconds, the setup panel will change from "No keyboard found" to "keyboard found". Don't let go of the button!
5. Now here is the key step. While still holding down that power button, don't let it go, you need to use your mouse to press "Next" on the dialog.
6. Connected.

Comment: Thanks a lot - this works, although you might have to repeat the process a few times.

Comment: This did not work for me for macOS Monterey 12.5.1.